# How can I update my ListView row

Tags: java, android, xml

I have added a data into listview by textboxes ....

I want to update rows of a listview by tapping on a ListView.
All row data is from the sqlite db and arrange the data again in my Textboxes.

The listview activity and Addactivity are separated ... 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehvwu.png)

I need your help

***SQLiteListAdapter.java:***

```
package com.androidstudio.myinventory;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by HP on 9/15/2017.
 */

public class SQLiteListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> Item_ID;
    ArrayList<String> ItemName;
    ArrayList<String> Quantity;


    ArrayList<String> Price;
    ArrayList<String> Value;
    //  ArrayList<String> Detail ;


    public SQLiteListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> item_ID, ArrayList<String> itemName,
                             ArrayList<String> quantity, ArrayList<String> price, ArrayList<String> value) {
        this.context = context;
        this.Item_ID = item_ID;
        this.ItemName = itemName;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
        this.Price = price;
        this.Value = value;
        //this.Detail = detail;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Item_ID.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View child, ViewGroup parent) {


        Holder holder;

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        //Check if this is the first time creating this row for the listview
        if (child == null) {

            //get the Android's layout inflater service which will read row_details.xml
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //Fill the row view with the xml layout file
            child = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_stock_row, null);

            //Row was null, need to get components from the row_details.xml
            holder = new Holder();
            //Fill the holder with the text view components
            holder.textviewid = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tvsr);
            holder.textviewname = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
            holder.textviewquantity = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tvquantity);
            holder.textviewprice = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tvprice);
            holder.textviewvalue = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tvvalue);
            //holder.textviewdetail = (TextView) child.findViewById(R.id.tvdetail);


            //attach the holder to the row
            child.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            //row was created before! thus get the holder object from the row tag
            holder = (Holder) child.getTag();
        }

        //At this point we have our row, either created from new or got it from the row tag object
        //we can now fill the data

        //get our object from the list which is in the position of the listview
        //position is passed to the getView method by the listview


        holder.textviewid.setText(Item_ID.get(position));
        holder.textviewname.setText(ItemName.get(position));
        holder.textviewquantity.setText(Quantity.get(position));
        holder.textviewprice.setText(Price.get(position));
        holder.textviewvalue.setText(Value.get(position));
        // holder.textviewdetail.setText(Detail.get(position));


        //return to listview to show
        return child;
    }

    //A holder will be responsible to hold the components to improve listview performance
//We replicate the components in the row_details.xml
    public class Holder {
        TextView textviewid;
        TextView textviewname;
        TextView textviewquantity;
        TextView textviewprice;
        TextView textviewvalue;
        // TextView textviewdetail;

    }

}
```

***Edit_Stock.java:***

```
package com.androidstudio.myinventory;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.CharArrayBuffer;
import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Edit_Stock extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String KEY1 = "key1";
    StockDBHelper stockDBHelper;
    SQLiteListAdapter ListAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    TextView textView;
    String search;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Cursor cursor;


    ArrayList<String> ID_ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> NAME_ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> QUANTITY_ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> PRICE_ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> VALUE_ArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    // ArrayList<String> DETAIL_ArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit__stock);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdetail);

        stockDBHelper = new StockDBHelper(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listviewedit);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        ShowSQLiteDBdata();

        super.onResume();
    }

    private void ShowSQLiteDBdata() {

        sqLiteDatabase = stockDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_stock1", null);

        ID_ArrayList.clear();
        NAME_ArrayList.clear();
        QUANTITY_ArrayList.clear();
        PRICE_ArrayList.clear();
        VALUE_ArrayList.clear();
        //DETAIL_ArrayList.clear();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ID_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stockDBHelper.COL_1)));

                NAME_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stockDBHelper.COL_2)));

                QUANTITY_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stockDBHelper.COL_10)));

                PRICE_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stockDBHelper.COL_9)));
                VALUE_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stockDBHelper.COL_5)));

                // DETAIL_ArrayList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(stockDBHelper.COL_7)));
               /* DETAIL_ArrayList.add(cursor.getColumnName(cursor.getColumnIndex(stockDBHelper.COL_7)));
                 DETAIL_ArrayList.iterator();
                 tvdetail.setText("Edit");*/
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        ListAdapter = new SQLiteListAdapter(Edit_Stock.this, ID_ArrayList,
                NAME_ArrayList,
                QUANTITY_ArrayList,
                PRICE_ArrayList,
                VALUE_ArrayList
                // DETAIL_ArrayList

        );

        listView.setAdapter(ListAdapter);

        cursor.close();
    }


    public void tveditClick(View view) {

        String name = "";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Edit_Stock.this, AddStock.class);


        startActivity(intent);


        Toast.makeText(this, "cliced", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //Edit works....................
    private void EditSQLiteDBdata() {
        // search=textView.toString();

    }
}
```

***AddStock.java:***

```
package com.androidstudio.myinventory;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class AddStock extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    EditText etproductname, etitemname, etbrand, etdate, etcompany, etprice, etquantity, etnotilimit, etlocation, etphoto;
    EditText etdetail;
    Spinner spinner_category;
    Button btnsave;
    StockDBHelper stockDBHelper;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_stock);


        stockDBHelper = new StockDBHelper(this);

        etproductname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etproduct_name);
        etitemname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etItem_name);
        etbrand = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etbrand);
        etdate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
        spinner_category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner_category);
        etdetail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdetail);
        etcompany = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcompany);
        etprice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etprice);
        etquantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etquantity);
        etnotilimit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etnoti_limit);
        etlocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etlocation);
        etphoto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etupdate_photo);

        btnsave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsave);

        pupulateSpinner();
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    }


    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mpickerDialog;

    //  etDate onClick event method
    public void datePick(View view) {
        etdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddStock.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth
                        , mpickerDialog, year, month, day);

                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        mpickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
                month = month + 1;
                Log.d("TAG", "onDateSet :" + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
                String date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
                etdate.setText(date);

            }
        };
    }


    // spinner populating method called in oncreate()
    public void pupulateSpinner() {
        spinner_category.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        // String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Categories);

      /*  ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_add_stock,list);
        spinner_category.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
*/

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.Categories, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner_category.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }

    ImageView image;
    Integer REQUEST_CAMERA = 1, SELECT_FILE = 0;

    public void photoClick(View view) {


        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery",
                "Cancel"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddStock.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);

                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");

                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }


        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {


            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                // onCaptureImageResult(data);
                Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
                final Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) bundle.get("data");
                image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                Uri selectphotoUri = data.getData();
                image.setImageURI(selectphotoUri);
            }


        }
    }


    // save button onClick event
    public void saveStock(View view) {
        // Button button=new Button(context);
        //button.setText("View");
        //etdetail.setText(text);*/

        etdetail.setText("View");
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                boolean isInserted = stockDBHelper.insertData(etitemname.getText().toString(), etproductname.getText().toString(),
                        etbrand.getText().toString(), etdate.getText().toString(), spinner_category.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                        etcompany.getText().toString(), etprice.getText().toString(), etquantity.getText().toString(),
                        etnotilimit.getText().toString(), etlocation.getText().toString(), etphoto.getText().toString());

                if (isInserted == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(AddStock.this, "Data inserted successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else
                    Toast.makeText(AddStock.this, "Data was not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }

}
```

***StockDBHelper.java***

```
package com.androidstudio.myinventory;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

/**
 * Created by HP on 9/10/2017.
 */

public class StockDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
         public static final String DB_NAME = "stock1.db";
         public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_stock1";
    public static final String COL_1 = "SERIAL";
    public static final String COL_2 = "ITEM_NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "PRODUCT_NAME";
    public static final String COL_4 = "BRAND";
    public static final String COL_5 = "DATE";
    public static final String COL_6 = "CATEGORY";
   // public static final String COL_7 = "DETAIL";
    public static final String COL_8 = "COMPANY";
    public static final String COL_9 = "PRICE";
    public static final String COL_10 = "QUANTITY";
    public static final String COL_11 = "NOTIFICATION_LIMIT";
    public static final String COL_12 = "LOCATION";
    public static final String COL_13 = "PHOTO";



    public StockDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DB_NAME, null, 3);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(SERIAL INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "ITEM_NAME TEXT,PRODUCT_NAME TEXT,BRAND TEXT, DATE INTEGER ,CATEGORY TEXT,COMPANY TEXT,PRICE INTEGER," +
                "QUANTITY INTEGER,NOTIFICATION_LIMIT INTEGER,LOCATION TEXT,PHOTO TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
       sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +   TABLE_NAME);
       onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String item_name,String product_name , String brand , String date , String category, String company,
                                   String price,String quantity, String noti_limit , String location,String photo)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,item_name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,product_name);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,brand);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,date);
        contentValues.put(COL_6,category);
        //contentValues.put(COL_7,detail);
        contentValues.put(COL_8,company);
        contentValues.put(COL_9,price);
        contentValues.put(COL_10,quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_11,noti_limit);
        contentValues.put(COL_12 ,location);
        contentValues.put(COL_13,photo);


        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

        if (result == -1)
        return  false;
        else
        return true;
    }
    public Cursor editdata(String id,SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase){
        Cursor cursor;
        String \[\] projection = {COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,COL_4,COL_5,COL_6,COL_8,COL_9,COL_10,COL_11,COL_12,COL_13};
        String selection= COL_1+ " LIKE ?";
        String\[\] selection_arg={id};

        cursor=sqLiteDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME,projection,selection,selection_arg,null,null,null);
        return cursor;
    }

    // Show data in listview editing
    /*public void ShowListData(String Id, String item_name , String quantity , String price , String value, String detail)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1,Id);
        contentValues.put(COL_2,item_name);
        contentValues.put(COL_10,quantity);
        contentValues.put(COL_9,price);
        // Value is to be brought by java coding
        contentValues.put(COL_7,detail);
    }*/
/*

    public Cursor insertDataIntoList(){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res=sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(" SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }
*/

}][2]
```

Comment: first edit your question. seprate your class

Comment: I am using Stakcoverflow for the first time .. so thats why

Answer (score 0):

Just take row's parent click in adapter and catch the ID column from that click.

```
Item_ID.get(position);
```

And then pass this through the intent to the Activity where you want to show all the data. And then get that ID and query to the database to get all the data.

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Thankx bro for such a fast reply ....   I am trying it .... will tell you

Comment: Babul bro I have tried but nothing works ... please share code here

Answer (score -1):

You can use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to refresh the listview.

Comment: He wants to get data using ID.

Comment: You can create function in the Adapter class to get the date,

Comment: Also please return something on your adapter Override functions to get the id and item.

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null; //Please return your object here not null
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0; //Please return your objects id here not 0
    }

Comment: public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Item_ID.get(position);
    }

 
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return Item_ID.indexOf(position);
    }

Comment: You can pass Item_ID.get(position); on your both functions.

Also why you are passing to Adapter like, 
  public SQLiteListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> item_ID, ArrayList<String> itemName,
                             ArrayList<String> quantity, ArrayList<String> price, ArrayList<String> value) 
Just create an  Object with item_ID, itemName, quantity, price, value. and pass the ArrayList of that object.